# UIView with UITapGestureRecognizer pass through drag to a UITableView beneath it?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've got a view hierarchy that looks like this:

```
* Root UIView
  * UITableView
  * UIView
```

The `UIView` is on "Top", so it occludes part of the `UITableView`.

The `UIView` also has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it that allows it to be tapped.

What I want is for the `UIView` to handle single taps, but pass the drag events down to the `UITableView` (so the UITableView can scroll). The tapping works fine, but the `UIView` swallows the drag events.

I have set `cancelsTouchesInView` but it doesn't help.

The repo for the following image can be found at https://github.com/SuperTango/TapGestureOnTopOfTableView

Here is a gif showing what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/@nguyenminhphuc/how-to-pass-ui-events-through-views-in-ios-c1be9ab1626b

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by adding UIPanGestureRecognizer to your TappableView. 
Here how i did it :

in your ViewController i add an IBoutlet of TappableView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pinkView: TappableView!
```

in TappableView i add a weak reference of your tableView :

```
 weak var tableView:UITableView?
```

in viewDidLoad of your ViewController we set the table reference of TappableView :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    pinkView.tableView = self.tableView
}
```

In TappableView I add an UIPanGestureRecognizer like this :

```
 // Here we add the PanGesture
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePanGesture(_:)))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
```

and finally i implement the action of pan gesture like this :

```
// Handle Pan gesture action
func handlePanGesture(_ panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = panGesture.translation(in: self)
    panGesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)

    if let tableView = self.tableView{
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: tableView.contentOffset.x, y: tableView.contentOffset.y + translation.y)
    }

}
```

**Complete Code of TappableView**

```
import UIKit

class TappableView: UIView {

weak var tableView:UITableView?
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

func setup() {
    let singleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    singleTapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tappedHandler(_:)))
    singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapRecognizer)

    // Here we add the PanGesture
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePanGesture(_:)))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}

func tappedHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    NSLog("Got a tap")
}


// Handle Pan gesture action
func handlePanGesture(_ panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = panGesture.translation(in: self)
    panGesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)

    if let tableView = self.tableView{
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: tableView.contentOffset.x, y: tableView.contentOffset.y + translation.y)
    }

}


}
```

**Complete Code of ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var pinkView: TappableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    pinkView.tableView = self.tableView
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = String(indexPath.row)
    return cell
}
}
```

Let me know if this resolve your problem